# Instantiate Prawn PDF Document from document render

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, pdf, prawn

I'm using [PrawnPDF](https://github.com/prawnpdf/prawn) to create a PDF file and then using [CombinePDF](https://github.com/boazsegev/combine_pdf) to append other files and render out the PDF for download. But I need to add anchors from the table content to the files that are appended afterwards so I want to be able to re-instantiate a `Prawn::Document` from the final rendered content, is there any way to do this? Or maybe someone can guide me to a better solution than the one I have in mind?

Comment: what do you mean by anchors? what do you want to be on your final outcome?

Comment: I mean hotlinks within the pdf to other sections of the PDF.